# Good source for posting videos to embed on your website

Tags: web-development

I have a website where I want to embed video tutorial on my blog posts. Now the video's that I make are HD and have not past the 10 min mark yet, maybe in the future.

Now I have the videos just on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com), it has HD, and all of them are under the 10 MIN. The only **downside** I have until now is that I haven't found a way to have a HD version of the vid embedded correctly on the page. If I choose HD the video player is 1280X960 on the page. The normal switch is not there.

Are there any good alternatives for this available online. I have checked [vimeo](http://vimeo.com), but for the HD version you have to pay. I make no money from the website so I am not willing to pay for that.

Are there any alternatives that I can use where I can post my videos. There are certain criteria I would like to have if possible.

*I want to be able to post HD .mp4's and the video's I embed on my website must have the function to play in HD.*

*I want to be able to make vids longer than 10 MIN.*

*It would be nice if the video site is popular, so it could attract some visitors to my website via the video's*

*This services have to be FREE*

I know that are a lot of requirements to ask for free, but this is just my ideal set-up, I could settle for less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using your site for commercial purposes I think your best best is JW PLayer from Longtail, http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/.  It isn't a hosted solution so you would have to host everything yourself but it will play HD files and do everything else you want.  I do believe to play HD files you will need to convert them into H.264 format though.

They also sell an enterprise edition which removes their logo from the player and can be used on corporate sites and such.  It costs a flat fee of $89 for unlimited use on one domain.  It sounds like the free version would work for you.

Beyond that YouTube and Vimeo are going to probably be about as good as it gets for free.  They own the majority of the video posting space so they can set the rules to some degree.